# Leave a Guild if there are more bots then members

Tags: discord.js

So I have been trying to make a way to have my Discord bot leave a guild if there are more bots then Members, I have looked everywhere and can't find anything about it and people are not very helpful, Can I get some help on this?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please edit your question and tell us what solutions you've tried/considered, and what has gone wrong with them? Some code you've tried would help a lot too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In discord.js v12 you do it like this:

```js
const memberCount = guild.members.cache.filter((member) => !member.user.bot).size;
const botCount = guild.members.cache.filter((member) => member.user.bot).size;

if (botCount > memberCount) {
  guild.leave().catch((err) => {
    console.log(`there was an error leaving the guild: \n ${err.message}`);
  });
}
```

First you'll get both the count of the actual guild members and the count of the bots. Don't forget the `cache` property in v12! 
Then we can check which number is larger and possibly leave the guild. 
You might want to run this code on `<Client>.on("message", (message) => {});`